# Running through crontab giving different results for python script

Tags: python, mongodb, cron

I wrote a python script to check whether mongod and supervisor are running correctly in my server.

```
import commands
c1 = commands.getstatusoutput("service mongod status")
c2 = commands.getstatusoutput("service supervisor status")
m = "---MongoDB: "+c1[1]
s = "---Supervisorctl: "+c2[1]
print m+s
```

The script will send output to my slack. The script works perfectly when run the script as normal.

```
python script.py
```

The output is recieved as
---MongoDB: mongod start/running, process 19714
---Supervisorctl:  is running

But when the same script is run in crontab i get different results

```
* * * * * python /root/checker/script.py
```

Output is

```
---MongoDB: mongod: unrecognized service
---Supervisorctl:  is running
```

I am running everything as root user. Any idea why crontab is giving different output for `service mongod status`

Comment: Are you sure the crontab is executed as the same user?

Comment: yes. I edit crontab when logged in as root user